# Return subsets in recursion - Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, subset, combinatorics

> I have to implement a recursive function which recieves only two arguments: 'n' and 'k', where n is the length of a set of from '0' to 'n-1' and k is the length of the subsets of different elements from the original set. We have to return finally a list of lists which contains these all sub-lists in k-length. The twist here that I don't know to overcome is we mustn't use other arguments such as lists, tuples, sets, etc...

So I don't know how to "save" in recursion the list of all subsets without "lost" details.

```
def ret_k_subset(n, k):
    if n >= 0 and k >= 0:
        lst = []
        if len(lst) == k:
            return lst
        else:
            for n in range(n):
                return lst + ret_k_subset(n, k)
    return lst
```

I thought of something like that but it always returns an empty list...
So I think I need to understand how do I save data structures consistently in recursion.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd pass *save* the recursion by passing it around as a list. But _we mustn't use other arguments such as lists, tuples, sets, etc..._

Comment: I haven't succeed to solve it yet...

Comment: Is the number of arguments fixed at `n` and `k` for can there be, say, other `int` arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in few ways, IMO the simplest is to take that recursion step that uses property that last element (n-1) is or isn't in result list and with appropriate recursion result construct it's result. Here is implementation:

```
def ret_k_subset(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return [[]]
    if k == n:
        return [list(range(n))]
    return ret_k_subset(n - 1, k) + [x + [n - 1] for x in ret_k_subset(n - 1, k - 1)]
```

Comment: I didn't understand actually what is the recursive step here? Why do you go only to n-1 element? And where is the relation to the n'th element?

Comment: I don't understand questions :-/ What do you mean that code only goes to n-1 element? Set of length n has elements 0, 1, ..., n-1. n'th element is n-1, and it is added with x+[n-1] part.